# Apply lowercase in specific column for certain group of countries in BQ?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to apply lowercase to product_name column for countries like FR, ES, but for the rest of them CA, IL, DE should be without any changes. I'm tryin with this query, but something doesn't work:

```
 SELECT
    id
    ,brand
    ,cern
    ,cern_3
    ,backpack
    ,qutoation
    ,product_name 
    ,CASE WHEN country_code in ('FR', 'ES') then lower(product_name) end
    ,category
    ,country_code
    ,timestamp
FROM table.name
```

Comment: You missed the ELSE part: `CASE WHEN country_code in ('FR', 'ES') then lower(product_name) ELSE product_name end`

Comment: Shouldn't this comment go as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query probably returns `null` for other countries, so as [@forpas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10498828/forpas) suggested in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72870861/apply-lowercase-in-specific-column-for-certain-group-of-countries-in-bq#comment128709110_72870861) add `else`:

```sql
CASE WHEN country_code in ('FR', 'ES') then lower(product_name) else product_name end
```